# python library Image processing- find image tearing

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm looking for a method to understand when an image has a tear in the data -

All I could think of is running vertically pixel by pixel and "understanding" major changes in data

tearing in image:

[image: tears in image - red circle is expected circle]

tears are always horizontal

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: What are the blue arrows and red circle trying to tell me exactly, please? Maybe you could show other examples of *"tearing"* and give some insights as to what causes it... and the source/nature of the images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - the blue arrows point to the tearing in this specific image, the red circle is the circle I expected to find - and couldn't due to tears

Comment: What causes this? Sure you can detect it, but wouldn’t it be better to prevent it in the first place?

Comment: @OriShalhno can you share the original image without the arrows on top of it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo My main goal is to prevent this - yet it is proven more difficult than just finding when this happens ..

Comment: @Bilal edited question - now has original picture

Answer (score 0):

Below are three thresholding techniques implemented in python opencv which require some trial and error to choose the threshold for your particular images. At the end of each code block below you will need to set a selection criteria (x <y) to categorize torn versus untorn images.

It is a good idea to convert the image to grayscale after reading it.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
    
path = r"C:\Your\filepath\here"  # Directory to get files from
    
img = cv.imread(path, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)  # Read image
    
g_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Covert image to grayscale
```

1. Canny Edge Detection + Hough Line Transform (generally applicable)

   Uses Canny edge detection to find edges and then a probabilistic Hough line transform to detect lines. Will detect lines in all orientations as well as natural lines in your images.

```py
## Canny parameters
low_threshold = 5  # below is not an edge
ratio = 3  # 2:1 or 3:1 typically recommended
upper_threshold = low_threshold * ratio  # above in an edge
kernel_size_c = 3  # kernel size

## HoughLinesP parameters
dist_reso_p = 1  # distance resolution of the accumulator (pixels)
ang_reso_p = np.pi / 180  # angle resolution of the acccumulator, typically set between 0 and 2*pi (radians)
hough_thresh_p = 400  # accumulator threshold
min_lin_len = 300  # minimum line length
max_lin_gap = 10  # minimum line gap

dst = cv.Canny(g_img, low_threshold, upper_threshold, None, kernel_size_c)  # Canny edge detector
linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, dist_reso_p, ang_reso_p, hough_thresh_p, None, min_lin_len, max_lin_gap)  # Probabilistic Hough line transform

if np.sum(linesP) == None:
    houghlines = 1
else:
    houghlines = np.sum(linesP)
```

2. Row Difference (most successful for my images with horizontal tears)

   Takes the difference between subsequent rows and compares against    a given threshold

```py
threshold = 10
tear_count = 0

for row in range(0, g_img.shape[0] - 1):
    row1 = g_img[row, :]
    row2 = g_img[row + 1, :]
    diff = cv.absdiff(row1, row2)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(diff, threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    if cv.countNonZero(thresh) > 0:
        tear_count += 1
```

3. Standard Deviation of the Laplacian (can detect other types of image issues as well)

```py
ddepth = cv.CV_16S  # desired depth of destination image
kernel_size = 3  # Aperture size used to compute the second-derivative filters
    
std = cv.Laplacian(g_img, ddepth, ksize=kernel_size).std()  # Get std of laplacian. If std is too high, maybe image tearing
```

I am sure there are better approaches to this problem, so hopefully you will get other answers as well.